# Google charts to show multiple tooltip

Tags: google-visualization, tooltip

I have folloing chart which has month wise equity and debt value

[image]

I need to show both the tooltip while mouse hover the month v-axis, i try to add `aggregationTarget: 'category'` but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, which is need to add `focusTarget: 'category'`